# javascript import got unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I got `a.js` and `b.js`, both of the file are placed within the same directory.

a.js

```
export function test() {
  return test
}
```

b.js

```
import { test } from './a'
```

I run

```
babel-node b.js
```

got unexpected token error, any clue why?

even I just do import path from 'path' in b.js I got this error

```
babel-node node_modules/.bin/mocha ./scripts/index.spec.js

/Users/Documents/myproject/scripts/index.spec.js:18
import path from 'path'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Any path error? share the error in detail

Comment: so import isn't supported in your current setup, can you share your `.babelrc` setup? Can you use `require` instead?

Comment: I do `const test = require('./index.js'); I got an empty object`

Comment: @Icepickle I don't think it's related to babel, I try to put an arrow function, it's fine, I think the path is not correct.

Comment: I think you're missing the `es2015` preset? Can you create a file with the name `.babelrc` in your project directory and add `{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}` in it and run again?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by creating a file named `.babelrc` in your project directory and adding the following in it:

```
{ 
    "presets": ["es2015"] 
}
```

Hope it will help!!